# Ninja Build System + gcc/clang doesn't output diagnostic colors

Tags: c++, c, ninja

When invoking [`ninja`](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja) on a *C or C++* (hence both tags) project, with the `clang` or `gcc` compiler, the output is not colored with ANSI colors.

For example:

`error` should be red, but isn't.
`warning` should be yellow/orange, but isn't.

Everything is the same color, and it's really hard to tell what's going on!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why this happens

This happens because `ninja` internally creates a `pipe()`, which stdout and stderr from the compiler (gcc or clang in this case) is re-routed. This makes the check inside gcc and clang, which checks for terminals (which may support color), fail.

A check such as `isatty(stdout)` does not return `true` for a pipe, even though that pipe is then forwarded to stdout once again.

### It's documented

[Ninja's FAQ talks about this on GitHub.com](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/wiki/FAQ#why-does-my-program-with-colored-output-not-have-color-under-ninja), but this FAQ is **not included** with the software, not mentioned in the `--help`, there are no ninja manpages, and common search engines (ddg, google) do not seem to find that FAQ for common search queries relating to color.

Hence, this post, since SO has good SSO.

### The fix

Add `-fdiagnostics-color=always` to your C or CXX flags. For example, with cmake, you can append `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fdiagnostics-color=always` (or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` for C) (or, if you are using CMake 3.24 or later, you can use [the `CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS.html) or [environment variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS.html#envvar:CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS)).

This works for gcc (as documented in its manpage) and clang (clang's manpages do not mention this option, but it is included in their [command line reference on llvm.org](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fcolor-diagnostics).

As a permanent fix, you could append the following to your `.zshrc`, `.bashrc`, or similar:

```bash
# force C colored diagnostic output
export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -fdiagnostics-color=always"
# force C++ colored diagnostic output
export CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS} -fdiagnostics-color=always"
export CCFLAGS="${CCFLAGS} -fdiagnostics-color=always"
# force C, C++, Cpp (pre-processor) colored diagnostic output
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -fdiagnostics-color=always"
```

You should only do this if you KNOW you will never need to pipe your compiler's output anywhere else. Also, this will only work with clang and gcc, and other compilers which support this - so make sure you dont use compilers that choke on this flag.

Comment: Yes, it's in the manual and FAQ. Why do you think it's worth to be a post here?

Comment: @273K My post covers this: "common search engines (ddg, google) do not seem to find that FAQ for common search queries relating to color"

Comment: unfortunately, neither `-fdiagnostics-color=always`, nor the supposed clang equivalent `-fcolor-diagnostics` do anything with ninja and apple clang these days.

Comment: Or that might be ccache-related, who knows. Anyway, seems impossible to get cmake+ninja+ccache+color on macos.

Comment: for me `-fdiagnostics-color=always` works for gcc 12.2.1 and clang 15.0.7 when called directly in zsh shell on linux, but when using ninja it only works for gcc, not for clang (I can see the `-fdiagnostics-color=always` in the call.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows 10 added support for ANSI escape codes.

```
-fansi-escape-codes
```

```
-fcolor-diagnostics
```

LLVM(Clang) on windows supports them since:

[image: since]

> -fansi-escape-codes
>
> ```
> Controls whether ANSI escape codes are used instead of 
> the Windows Console API to output colored diagnostics.
> This option is only used on Windows and defaults to off.
> ```

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-fansi-escape-codes

Ninja should handle it:

[image: ninja test]